# Chrome extension sendMessage response timeout when?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a background script that might wait a long time before a sendMessage-response is sent (it could be hours). I got an error message `The message port closed before a response was received`. After how long time will the message port close? And is there a way to keep the message port open longer?

Comment: There should be no such limit. The error you see is usually caused by an incorrect use of messaging callback/sendResponse. It's not the only reason though so without [MCVE](/help/mcve) I can't help.

Comment: Aha, ok, thanks, will investigate...